# How do I delete empty NLA tracks and why are they so randomly created?`

Tags: animation, nla-editor

I can't seem to delete unwanted tracks when I have the "Include Missing NLA" button selected. What bothers me more is it seems to create tracks by random.  In the screen shot below, 1/4 lights have an NLA track, my camera has an NLA track, the Mesh Body that is attached to my Armature has an NLA track and the armature itself has an NLA track.  Also the eyeballs have one. This seems very random, where do these tracks come from? Why are they so random?  Is it possible to clean them up?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must have given an action to these objects at one point. But to remove all the useless tracks, right click and *Remove Empty Animation Data*:

[image]

You can also activate the *Only Show Selected* option, which will allow you to only see the track of the selected object(s):

[image]

Comment: This method doesn't work.  It literally empties the animation data, but the "eyeball" and the "Body" objects with empty tracks are still there.

Comment: Please share your file (remove all the useless objects): https://blend-exchange.com/